# aggregate in multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has two level column indices. I need to have different aggregation functions on two keys (columns). However, I received an error on my code. How can I aggregate on multiple columns in multilevel dataframe.

```
dic1 = {('count', 'N.A.'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 0,
  Period('1993-02', 'M'): 0,
  Period('1993-03', 'M'): 0},
 ('count', 'No'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 1,
  Period('1993-02', 'M'): 1,
  Period('1993-03', 'M'): 1},
 ('count', 'Yes'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 0,
  Period('1993-02', 'M'): 0,
  Period('1993-03', 'M'): 0},
 ('sum', 'N.A.'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): nan,
  Period('1993-02', 'M'): nan,
  Period('1993-03', 'M'): nan},
 ('sum', 'No'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 6.5820000000000007,
  Period('1993-02', 'M'): 131.1865,
  Period('1993-03', 'M'): 133.31049999999999},
 ('sum', 'Yes'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): nan,
  Period('1993-02', 'M'): nan,
  Period('1993-03', 'M'): nan}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)

df1.to_timestamp(how='end').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('A') ).agg(
{'count':['max', 'min', 'median', 'last'] , 
 'sum':['mean', 'max' , 'last']} )

error:  KeyError: 'sum'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the column MultiIndex before grouping:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
df2 = df1.to_timestamp(how='end')
df2 = df2.rename_axis(['operation', 'YN'], axis=1)
df3 = df2.stack(level='YN').reset_index('YN')
# operation     YN  count       sum
# 1993-01-31  N.A.      0       NaN
# 1993-01-31    No      1    6.5820
# 1993-01-31   Yes      0       NaN
# 1993-02-28  N.A.      0       NaN
# 1993-02-28    No      1  131.1865
# 1993-02-28   Yes      0       NaN
# 1993-03-31  N.A.      0       NaN
# 1993-03-31    No      1  133.3105
# 1993-03-31   Yes      0       NaN
```

Once you've moved the `YN` column index level into a column (by calling
`stack/reset_index`), you can approach the problem in the usual way:

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Period = pd.Period
nan = np.nan

dic1 = {('count', 'N.A.'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 0, Period('1993-02', 'M'): 0, Period('1993-03', 'M'): 0}, ('count', 'No'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 1, Period('1993-02', 'M'): 1, Period('1993-03', 'M'): 1}, ('count', 'Yes'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 0, Period('1993-02', 'M'): 0, Period('1993-03', 'M'): 0}, ('sum', 'N.A.'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): nan, Period('1993-02', 'M'): nan, Period('1993-03', 'M'): nan}, ('sum', 'No'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): 6.5820000000000007, Period('1993-02', 'M'): 131.1865, Period('1993-03', 'M'): 133.31049999999999}, ('sum', 'Yes'): {Period('1993-01', 'M'): nan, Period('1993-02', 'M'): nan, Period('1993-03', 'M'): nan}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
df2 = df1.to_timestamp(how='end')
df2 = df2.rename_axis(['operation', 'YN'], axis=1)
df3 = df2.stack(level='YN').reset_index('YN')

grouped = df3.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('A'), 'YN'])
result = grouped.agg(
    {'count':['max', 'min', 'median', 'last'],  'sum':['mean', 'max' , 'last']})
result = result.unstack('YN')
print(result)
```

yields

```
            sum                                                      count  \
           mean                 max               last                 max   
YN         N.A.         No Yes N.A.        No Yes N.A.        No Yes  N.A.   
1993-12-31  NaN  90.359667 NaN  NaN  133.3105 NaN  NaN  133.3105 NaN     0   

           ...                                            
           ...      min        median        last         
YN         ... Yes N.A. No Yes   N.A. No Yes N.A. No Yes  
1993-12-31 ...   0    0  1   0      0  1   0    0  1   0
```

Comment: Thanks! `reset_index(-1)` is for make pandas repeat the dates or it has other functions?

Comment: [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) moves the index (or, in the case of a MultiIndex, a level or levels of the MultiIndex) to columns of the DataFrame. `reset_index(-1)` moves the last level of the MultiIndex to a column. In this case it moves the `YN` index level into a new column of the same name. `reset_index(-1)` is useful when the last level does not have a name. Here, I should have used `reset_index('YN')` since that is more descriptive.

Comment: [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) moves the column index (or level(s) of a column MultiIndex) to the row index. Together, `stack` followed by `reset_index` moves a level of the column index into a new DataFrame column.

Comment: The data in a Pandas DataFrame adjusts itself as necessary to accomodate the shape of the column and row indexes.  New rows (with repeated dates) were added when we called `stack` because each date corresponds with 3 `YN` values. See also [Reshaping by stacking and unstacking](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking) in the doc.

Comment: Nive! Thanks @unutbu

Answer (score 2):

A kind of hacky way to do this is to pull out all the count and sum columns respectively:

```
In [11]: agg_dict = {col: ['mean', 'max' , 'median', 'last'] for col in df1.columns[df1.columns.get_level_values(0) == "count"]}

In [12]: agg_dict.update({col: ['mean', 'max' , 'last'] for col in df1.columns[df1.columns.get_level_values(0) == "sum"]})

In [13]: g = df1.to_timestamp(how='end').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('A') )

In [14]: g.agg(agg_dict)
Out[14]:
            sum                                                       count
           N.A.                  No                      Yes           N.A.                   No                  Yes
           mean max last       mean       max      last mean max last  mean max median last mean max median last mean max median last
1993-12-31  NaN NaN  NaN  90.359667  133.3105  133.3105  NaN NaN  NaN     0   0      0    0    1   1      1    1    0   0      0    0
```